# find $f(1)$ if relation between $f'(x)$ and $f(x^2)$ is given

Tags: functions

If $f(x^2) + f'(x) = 6x^2 +7x+2$,
find the value of $f(1)$.
I tried to differentiate $3$ times and but then $f''''(1)$ is not getting eliminated. Can $f(x)$ be linear?

Comment: Is it only $f(1)$ what you need to find? If so, note that evaluating the functional equation at $x=1$ you get that $2f(1)=f(1^2)+f(1)=6+7+2$, from where you can solve for $f(1)$.

Comment: "Can $f(x)$ be linear?"  No.  $f(0)=f(0^2)$ should have been equal to $0$ if it were linear, but $f(0)+f(0)=6\cdot 0^2+7\cdot 0 + 2=2\neq 0$

Comment: sorry had a typo.. second term was f’(x)

Comment: why is question being downvoted

Comment: I tried to look for a power series of $f(x)$ and found $$
f(x) = a + (2 - a)x + \frac{7}{2}x^2  + \frac{{4 + a}}{3}x^3  + 0 \cdot x^4  - \frac{7}{{10}}x^5  + 0 \cdot x^6  - \frac{{a + 4}}{{21}}x^7  + 0 \cdot x^8  +  \cdots 
$$ where $a$ is an arbitrary real or complex constant.

Comment: @maveric Where did you find this problem?

Comment: Just an observation: Define $g$ via $7f(x)=g(x)+6x-4$.  Then the problem reduces to $g'(x)+g(x^2)=x$.  Also $f$ can't be a polynomial of any degree.

Comment: Ups, should be $f(x)=7g(x)+6x-4$.

Answer (score 2):

There's not enough information to determine $f(1)$.

By letting $f(x)=7g(x)+6x-4$ we're searching for
functions satisfying
$$g(x^2)+g'(x)-x=0.$$
We'll show that $f(1)$ depends on whatever we choose $a:=g(0)$ to be.

To construct $g$ we first define $d_j=(3\cdot2^{j-1}-1)$ and
$$\begin{align}h_0(x)&=
\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^5}{2\cdot5}+\frac{x^{11}}{2\cdot5\cdot11}\\
&-\frac{x^{23}}{2\cdot5\cdot11\cdot23}\cdots(-1)^{j+1}
\frac{x^{d_j}}{\prod_{k=1}^{j}d_k }\cdots \end{align}.$$
We go one defining $b_j=(2^n-1)$ and
$$\begin{align}h(x)&=
1-\frac{x}{1}+
\frac{x^3}{1\cdot3}\\
&-\frac{x^7}{1\cdot3\cdot7}+\frac{x^{15}}{1\cdot3\cdot7\cdot15}\\
&-\frac{x^{31}}{1\cdot3\cdot7\cdot15\cdot31}\cdots(-1)^{j+1}
\frac{ x^{b_j}}{\prod_{k=1}^{j}b_k}\cdots \end{align}.$$
Verify that the radius of convergence of both series equals $1$.  Due to Leibniz both series are convergent at $x=1$.

Finally define
$$\begin{align}g_a(x)=h_0(x)+a\cdot h(x)&=a-ax\\
&+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}\cdot a\\
&-\frac{x^5}{2\cdot5}-\frac{x^7}{3\cdot7}\cdot a\\
&+\frac{x^{11}}{2\cdot5\cdot11}+\frac{x^{15}}{3\cdot7\cdot15}\cdot a\\
&-\frac{x^{23}}{2\cdot5\cdot11\cdot23}-\frac{x^{31}}{3\cdot7\cdot15\cdot31}\cdot a\cdots
\end{align}$$

For example
$$g_0(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^5}{10}
+\frac{x^{11}}{110}-\frac{x^{23}}{2530}
+\frac{x^{47}}{118910}-\frac{x^{95}}{11296450}+\cdots,
$$
hence
$$g_0(x^2)=\frac{x^4}{2}-\frac{x^{10}}{10}
+\frac{x^{22}}{110}-\frac{x^{46}}{2530}+\frac{x^{94}}{118910}-\cdots$$
and
$$g_0'(x)=
x-\frac{x^4}{2}+\frac{x^{10}}{10}
-\frac{x^{22}}{110}+\frac{x^{46}}{2530}-\frac{x^{94}}{118910}+\cdots$$
Approximately we have $g_a(1)=0.408704 + 0.288788 a$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(1)=a$ and  $f'(1)=b.$ (The key idea: Stay close to $1$.)  Let $g(t)=f(1+t)$ so that $g'(t)=f'(1+t).$ After replacing $x$ by $1+t,$
the right side becomes $$ 15+19t+6t^2 \tag 1$$
Let $$g(t)=a+bt+ct^2. \tag 2$$
It follows that that
$$ g'(t)=b+2ct. \tag 3 $$
Henceforth, we suppress $t^3$ and higher terms. (Imagine that $t$ is less that $10^{-100}.$)

There is an important wrinkle here. I am assuming that the expression in (2) is *exact*, not just an approximation. Thus, we get the nice expression in (2). Is this legal? Yes, because we're only interested in the values of $g$ and $g'$ at zero.

Also,
$$f(x^2)=f((1+t)^2)=g(2t+t^2)=a+b(2t+t^2)+c(2t+t^2)^2\ \text{so that}$$
$$f(x^2)=a+2bt+(b+4c)t^2 \tag 4$$

We now equate coefficients in the equation $(4)+(3)=(1)$ to obtain
$$a={13\over 3},\  b={32\over 3}, \ c=-{7\over 6}$$

Comment: What is $h$ in $g(h)$?

Comment: solution is not clear.

Comment: Why in (4) there are not terms of degree 3 and 4?
Actually it is quite easy to show that no polynomial can satisfy the given equation.

Comment: $g(h)$ should be $g(t)$ and $g'(h)$ should be $g'(t).$  We're dealing with approximations, not polynomials. And it should be $|t|$ is less than $10^{-100}.$

Comment: I've had no reaction from Desperado. (If he didn't award me the $-1,$ he should tell me. Otherwise, I'm assuming he did.) He asked "Why in (4) there are not terms of degree 3 and 4?"   
My answer is: from where? (1) is degree 2 and $g(t)$ has been REPLACED
by the first three terms of its Taylor series in (2).  Higher order terms were omitted as usual when working $o(t^2).$ I am confident that my approximation for $g(t)$ is robust enough to pass through OP's constraint and exit with its value and first derivative (at zero) intact. (I'm working in an infinitesimal neighborhood of zero.)

Comment: @David I remove the downvote since your idea is now clear.  Your wrote "I am assuming that the expression in (2) is exact, not just an approximation", so I thought you where looking for a quadratic solution, not an approximation, you should have add $+o(t^2)$ in the formulas. Nevertheless, you only find an approximation for $f(1)$ and not its value as the OP asked for.

Comment: if i have 2 before f(x^2) , i m able to solve

Comment: @Gary Thank you for spotting the typo and editing my reply into my answer. Based on your qualifications, I'll remove my answer if you analyze it and reject it.

Answer (score 0):

As an outsider, I'm unable to add a comment to Michael Hoppe's post.
Nevertheless, let me remark that a Taylor series about $x=1$ would
make a lot more sense. (About zero, you have an unknown function with an
unknown radius of convergence.)

Comment: True, but $g_0(1)$ is convergent as Leibniz tells us.